# будет ли работать кали линукс с интелом?

Tags: linux, ос, kali-linux, amd, intel

скачал я `kali-linux-2021.3-installer-amd64.iso` но в имени есть amd64, будет ли работать кали линукс на Intel?извиняюсь если вопрос показался вам странным, я просто не особо разбираюсь в этом

Comment: amd64 это всего лишь название архитектуры, Intel использует ту же самую архитектуру и название тут никак не мешает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`amd64` это название архитектуры, придуманной в AMD. Интел использует её почти во всех своих процессорах. Другие названия этой архитектуры https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

У интела была и своя архитектура на 64 бит, но она появилась не получила широкого распространения из-за несовместимости с x86.

Comment: А что за своя архитектура, появившаяся второй, и когда это произошло по сравнению с amd64?

Comment: Амд представила свои расширения для x86 в 2000году. 
Itanium выпустили в 2001 году, но она не была совместима с х86. Позже интел выпустили реализацию EM64T совместимую с AMD64

Comment: Где вы вычитали про «второй» Интел!? Анонс был в 1999,

Comment: ia-64, конечно, была раньше: итаниумы — 2001 год, а оптироны — 2003, а провалилась она т.к. не была совместима с x86...

Comment: Intel представила свою IA64 раньше, чем AMD представила свою amd64; Intel выпустила свой Merced раньше, чем AMD выпустила свой Opteron.

Answer (score 3):

Будет. AMD первые разработали 64 битную архитектуру, поэтому так называется

Comment: Первые для расширения x86, а [вообще-то](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/64_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0), первой была еще в 1961 году IBM с ее 7030 Stretch

Answer (score 0):

Начиная с 3 го поколения работает не плохо (Intel Core Ix 3xxx).